# What is the advantage of using $f^\prime$ instead of $f'$?

Tags: math-mode, best-practices

Although the two outputs look quite similar, what is the advantage of using `$f^\prime$` instead of `$f'$`?
By the way, here is my code:

```
\documentclass‎{article‎}‎
\begin{document}‎‎‎
\[‎ ‎f^‎\prime ‎(x)=y‎ ‎\]‎
\[‎ ‎f'‎ ‎(x)=y‎ ‎\]‎‎
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's *no* advantage in using `$f^\prime$`; it's just more awkward to type than `$f'$` and the result is *exactly* the same.

Comment: just don't do f^'

Comment: Actually, there is one situation you need `^\prime`; when you want to make a parenthesis around the `\prime` so that you denote it applies to *un-primed* and *primed* respectively, you cannot do something like `$f^('^)$`, you would need `$f^{(\prime)}$`.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `'` is a shorthand for `^{\prime}`.

---

`'` is defined in `latex.ltx` as active math character:

```
\def\active@math@prime{^\bgroup\prim@s}
{\catcode`\'=\active \global\let'\active@math@prime}
\def\prim@s{%
  \prime\futurelet\@let@token\pr@m@s}
\def\pr@m@s{%
  \ifx'\@let@token
    \expandafter\pr@@@s
  \else
    \ifx^\@let@token
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@t
    \else
      \egroup
    \fi
  \fi}
\def\pr@@@s#1{\prim@s}
\def\pr@@@t#1#2{#2\egroup}
```

The active `'` looks for following `'` and puts them together as superscript,
`a'''` becomes `a^{\prime\prime\prime}`. Thus using `'` makes the input easier to write.

Answer (score 17):

Sometimes you may want to pass LaTeX code as an argument to another program. In that case the code is typically wrapped in quotes. Using quote to mean a prime will confuse the second program. For example to  type TeX in graphical output of MATLAB one may use something like

```
str='$$F^\prime$$'
text(0,0,str,'Interpreter','latex')
```

to print $F'$ at location $(0,0)$. Using $F'$ in the code however becomes problematic.

Comment: use double quotes or escapes for the String?

Comment: @MaxNoe Double quotes don't work in Matlab. String escaping is done with a double quote. So you'd have to write things like `'The symbol f'' is used to represent the first derivative of a function'`, which looks wrong at a first glance. All things considered, `f^\prime` doesn't look so bad.

Answer (score 8):

**Tl;DR:** You can use `\prime` with additional superscripts.

There is certainly one advantage to using `\prime` under a particular situation. Suppose you have a map `\pi` which necessitates the use of another map `\pi'`, which at first seems to be appropriately named.

That is, until you have to pullback something with respect to `\pi'`. Now you can either write `(\pi')^*` or `\pi^{\prime,*}`. The latter looks, arguably, a little better.

But both look horrible.

Comment: `\pi'^{,*}` is perfectly equivalent to `\pi^{\prime,*}`

Comment: @egreg `\pi'^{,*}` fails with error "double superscript"; `\pi^{\prime,*}` doesn't (using `scrartcl` and `amsmath`). So I prefer the latter … ;-)

Comment: @CL. Works for me with a minimal document. Some more details would be necessary.

Comment: @egreg Figured it out. It's the `breqn` package that breaks it. [MWE](https://pastebin.com/DKvNadkC).

Comment: @CL. Besides equations, `breqn` breaks so many things…

Comment: @MWE And now, OverLeaf decided that using `'` would be against its syntax commands.  Possibly for that very reason.

Answer (score 2):

I give a practical difference for Emacs users.

If you write `$x^{\prime\prime}$` it is all right, if you write `$x''$` you completely mess up the AUCTeX syntax coloring.

Comment: Which version opf AUCTEX, I have no issues with `$x''$`

Comment: "12.1.1" I am using the default latex configuration of the latest release version of Spacemacs, so I guess many other people share my latex setting

Comment: Interesting, I still use 11.90. Just had a PhD student come by yesterday, who also had problems with AUCTEX 12.1.1, which went away when he downgraded (he installed the Emacs + auctex for Windows there is on CTAN, instead). Seems like I'd better stay of 12.1 for while. Perhaps you should mention this on the auctex mailiing this such that they are aware of the issue.

Comment: I reported the issue

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there's a slight difference when you have two superscripts. For instance:

```
{\bar{e}_k}^{\prime\dag}
{\bar{e}_k}^{'\dag}
```

The first one fits better.

Comment: Sure, but that's related to `'` being the same as `^{\prime}`, so if you have `foo^{'\dag}` your prime symbol is superscripted twice. `{\bar{e}_k}'^{\dag}` will give identical output as far as my eye can tell, but I agree your input is more elegant. Also fiddling with the my input led me to a double superscript error, which is frankly what I expected to begin with, so using `foo^{\prime\dag}` is definitely a nice idea here, I think

Comment: You should type `\bar{e}_k'^{\dag}` (the braces around `\bar{e}_k` do nothing).

Answer (score 1):

Although `'` is a shorthand for `^\prime` as noted in answers above, this can get in your way when dealing with multiple superscripts in combination with subscripts:

```
\pi_{s+r}^{\ast\prime} = 
\pi^{\ast\prime}_{s+r} \ne 
\pi^{\ast}'_{s+r}      \ne 
\pi_{s+r}^{\ast}'
```