# My prime symbol is not superscript

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

I'm learning math mode and having an issue here with the prime symbol.

```
$y\in[0,1]^{d\prime}$
```

In this inline math formula, the prime symbol is supposed to be superscript, but it shows up at the regular text level and size.

Comment: If you provide a fuller example showing which files and packages you're loading, we could help you better

Comment: Informative (and a little bit related): [What is the advantage of using $f^\prime$ instead of $f'$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87134)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is not clear what you want the output to be

```
$y\in[0,1]^{d\prime}$
```

the `\prime` is in the superscript along with `d`. If you want the prime to be on `d` then just use

```
$y\in[0,1]^{d'}$
```

which is equivalent to

```
$y\in[0,1]^{d^{\prime}}$
```

Comment: Thank you. I needed the extra explanation as well as the answer. I'm not up to speed on this language.

Comment: +1 for noting apostrophe (`'`) is, in math mode, the same as `^{\prime}`

Comment: @AlexNelson, I think that that's only approximately true.  Namely, `\(d'\)` is the same (I guess) as `\(d^\prime\)`, but `\(d''\)` is not the same as `\(d^\prime^\prime\)`.  (I think `'` does some `\ifnextchar` monkeying precisely to handle this.)

Comment: @LSpice `\futurelet` rather than `\@ifnextchar`  but yes.

Answer (score 22):

`\prime` is by default on the same level as normal text. (Just as `\circ` - used as symbol for degrees for example.) Instead you need to specify that `\prime` is a superscript:

```
$y\in[0,1]^{d^\prime}$
```

**EDIT**: This might be marginal to the question, but I think it's a useful addition. The `'` is a shorthand for `^\prime`. Thus, if you type in LaTeX:

```
$y\in[0,1]^{d^{\circ'}}$
```

the output will be:

[image: double superscript]

As you can see, LaTeX interprets it as a double superscript. Now suppose you don't want that, but instead something like:

[image: no double superscript]

If you try to do it by typing: `$y\in[0,1]^{d^{\circ}'}$`, you'll summon up an error:

```
! Double superscript.
<recently read> ^
l.4 $y\in[0,1]^{d^{\circ}'
```

To avoid this, `\prime` comes handy. Just do: `$y\in[0,1]^{d^{\circ\prime}}$` and everything will be fine. `:)`

Comment: Duplicated from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96558/my-prime-symbol-is-not-superscript/96562#comment597598_96562:  I think that "The `'` is a shorthand for `^\prime`." is only approximately true. Namely, `\(d'\)` is the same (I guess) as `\(d^\prime\)`, but `\(d''\)` is not the same as `\(d^\prime^\prime\)`. (I think `'` does some `\ifnextchar` monkeying precisely to handle this.)