# I am using Texniccenter and facing an error for missing { in figure caption while every thing is looking fine

Tags: errors

I got a message for missing { inserted in caption

```
\caption{Schematic of band alignment due to the contact formation between
metal and n-type semiconductor. Here, $\phi_{MS}$ is the difference of
metal work function ($\phi_M$) and semiconductor work function ($\phi_S$),
E$_F$ is the Fermi energy level of metal, E$_F$ is the Fermi energy level
of semiconductor, E$_C$ is the the conduction band (CB) minima, E$_V$ is
the valence band (VB) maxima and  $\phi_S^'$ is Shottky barrier
height  [Piprek\cite{AB2}].}
```

and `.lof` file open with text

```
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1.1}{\ignorespaces Schematic of band
alignment due to the contact formation between metal and n-type
semiconductor. Here, $\phi _{MS}$ is the difference of metal work function
($\phi _M$) and semiconductor work function ($\phi _S$), E$_F$ is the
Fermi energy level of metal, E$_F$ is the Fermi energy level of
semiconductor, E$_C$ is the the conduction band (CB) minima, E$_V$ is the
valence band (VB) maxima and $\phi _S^'$ is Shottky barrier height
[Piprek\cite {AB2}].}}{6}{figure.1.1}
```

Can any body help whats wrong in this

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without any really line of code and document to work with this is difficult.

Comment: It is best to post code that reproduces the error or at the very least post the full error message from `! to `?` in a code section on the question. probably you have a fragile command in the caption that needs `\protect`, which could be some definitions of `\cite` but the fragments you show do not show any obvious error

Comment: unrelated to the error but why are you using weird markup like ` E$_V$ `  and `$\phi_S^'$ `  rather than `$\mathrm{E}_V$` and `$\phi'_S$` ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `$\phi_S^'$`. LaTeX interprets an apostrophe in math mode as a superscript prime, so there is no difference between `\phi_S'` and `\phi_S^\prime`. Thus, if you write `\phi_S^'`, it will be interpreted as `\phi_S^^\prime`, which is a double superscript and causes the error you got.

The correct way to write it is `$\phi_S'$`.

See also [this TeX.SX post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87134/55879).