# Making picture like a circle with pointing edges in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw (1, 0) to[bend left=45] (0.94, 0.34) to [bend left=45] (0.77,0.64);
    \draw (1, 0) to[bend right=45] (0.94, -0.34) to [bend right=45] (0.77,-0.64);
    \draw (-0.77,-0.64) to[bend right=45] (-0.94,-0.34) to [bend right=45] (-1,0);
    \draw (-1, 0) to[bend right=45] (-0.94, 0.34) to [bend right=45] (-0.77,0.64);

    \draw [thin,black] (-0.77,0.64) to[out=10,in=260] (-0.34,1);
    \draw [thin,black] (0.77,0.64) to[out=170,in=280] (0.34,1);

    \begin{scope}[dotted]
    \draw [thin,black] (0.77,-0.64) to[out=220,in=320] (-0.77,-0.64);
    \end{scope}

    \draw [thin,black] (-0.34,1) to[out=270,in=120] (-0.255,0.66);
    \draw [thin,black] (-0.255,0.66) to[out=60,in=260] (-0.17,1);
    \draw [thin,black] (-0.17,1) to[out=280,in=120] (-0.085,0.66);
    \draw [thin,black] (0.255,0.66) to[out=60,in=260] (0.34,1);

    \begin{scope}[dotted]
    \draw [thin,black] (-0.085,0.66) to [out=0,in=180] (0.255,0.66);
    \end{scope}

    \node[point, label=above:{\scalebox{0.5}{$\alpha_1$}}] at (-0.90,0.23) {};

    \node[point, label=above:{\scalebox{0.5}{$\beta_1$}}] at (-1,-0.15) {};
    \node[point, label=above:{\scalebox{0.5}{${\alpha^'}_1$}}] at (-1.03,-0.5) {};

    \node[point, label=above:{\scalebox{0.5}{${\beta^'}_1$}}] at (-0.91,-0.85) {};
    #######
    \node[point, label=above:{\scalebox{0.5}{${\alpha}_g$}}] at (0.91,-0.85) {};
    \node[point, label=above:{\scalebox{0.5}{${\beta}_g$}}] at (1.03,-0.5) {};
    \node[point, label=above:{\scalebox{0.5}{${\alpha^'}_g$}}] at (1,-0.15) {};
    \node[point, label=above:{\scalebox{0.5}{${\beta^'}_g$}}] at (0.90,0.21) {};
    #######
     \node[point, label=above:{\scalebox{0.3}{${\gamma}_1$}}] at (-0.49,0.54) {};
      \node[point, label=above:{\scalebox{0.3}{${\gamma^'}_r$}}] at (0.49,0.54) {};
      \node[point, label=above:{\scalebox{0.3}{${\gamma^'}_1$}}] at (-0.26,0.54) {};
      \node[point, label=above:{\scalebox{0.3}{${\gamma}_r$}}] at (0.26,0.54) {};

 \node[point, label=below:{\scalebox{0.3}{$\frac{2\pi}{m_1}$}}] at (-0.375,1) {};
 \node[point, label=below:{\scalebox{0.3}{$\frac{2\pi}{m_r}$}}] at (0.375,1) {};



\draw [thin,black] (-0.43,0.81) to[out=315,in=225] (-0.32,0.80);
\draw [thin,black] (0.31,0.80) to[out=315,in=225] (0.43,0.81);
\draw [thin,black] (-0.205,0.78) to[out=315,in=225] (-0.13,0.78);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to adjust \gamma_2 and \gamma'_2 in the diagram but it is not getting adjust. Could anyone help me to sort it out. Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: @Stefan. I intend to ask about hints of allocating points on a circle so I could use "bend" command to resolve this problem.

Comment: Also look up `to` and `arc`.

Comment: Well, what do you have? Why have you labelled this `circuitikz` and `tikz-external`? Where are the `tikz-arrows` supposed to come into it? What do you mean 'hints'? Where are the points supposed to go? If, say, you want them at 10, 20, 30 etc. degrees, use `\foreach \i [count=\n] in {10,20,...,350} \coordinate (c\n) at (\i:<radius>);` to set coordinates. If that's not what you mean, I'm clueless. That's my best guess.

Comment: How are you trying to adjust it? What do you expect to get that you're not getting?

Comment: What are all those hashes for? Very weird.

Comment: Please make sure that your examples actually work (unless of course, you're asking about an error). The `point` style is undefined, all the `#` symbols are just wrong, and you need `'`, not `^'`, as `'` is a shorthand for `^{\prime}` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87134). What exactly do you want to adjust?