# Plotting multiple functions in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, graphics

I have a function that I want to graph. However, there are 10 variations of it with 5 different constants each. I do not want to simply plug in a number 50 times. Is there an easier way to do this? Also, the graph comes out strangely. Is there an alternative to `pgfplots`that I use to generate an image and then just use `includegraphics`, preferably something with vector graphics so that it is of the highest quality. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.16}

\begin{document}


\[ y^{\prime} ( t ) = \frac{\lambda \phi ( \beta - \alpha )}{t \left[ 1 + ( t/\gamma)^{-\phi} \right]^\lambda \left[ 1 + (t/\gamma)^{\phi} \right]} \] 


\begin{figure}[htbp!]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{axis}[
      legend pos=north east,
      title = {},
      xlabel = {time},
      ylabel = {temperature},
      xmin = 0, xmax = 15,
      ymin = 0, ymax = 8,
      xtick = {0, 5, 10, 15},
      ytick = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8},
    ]

      \addplot[black, no marks, domain=0.01:15, smooth]{(1.86*3.38*(42.2 - 23.3))/(x*(1 + (x/3.15)^(-3.38))^(1.86)*(1 + (x/3.15)^(3.38)))};
      \addlegendentry{fitted function}

      \addplot[red, no marks, domain=0.01:15, smooth]{(12*3.01*(43.6 - 23.8))/(x*(1 + (x/1.38)^(-3.01))^(12)*(1 + (x/1.38)^(3.01)))};
      \addlegendentry{fitted function2}

    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what `declare function` is for.

Comment: @marmot Thank you, but an example please? Also any suggestions for making the graph look better or other options? Edit. I spoke too soon. I think I can figure out the `declare function`. Though example would be nice in case I screw it up.

Comment: Off-topic. [There is no difference between `^\prime` and `'`; the latter makes the code easy to write](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87134/152550).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare functions with the key `declare function`. (The Ti*k*Z library `math` has additional means to define functions, but this does not harmonize that well with `pgfplots` because `pgfplots` uses `fpu`.) Here is an example. This reproduces your plot with a declared function.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.16}

\begin{document}


\[ y^{\prime} ( t ) = \frac{\lambda \phi ( \beta - \alpha )}{t \left[ 1 + ( t/\gamma)^{-\phi} \right]^\lambda \left[ 1 + (t/\gamma)^{\phi} \right]} \] 


\begin{figure}[htbp!]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\x,\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\lambda,\phi)=%
  (\lambda*\phi*( \beta - \alpha ))/(\x*pow( 1 + pow( \x/\gamma,-\phi),\lambda) 
  *( 1 + pow(\x/\gamma,\phi)));}]
     \begin{axis}[
      legend pos=north east,
      title = {},
      xlabel = {time},
      ylabel = {temperature},
      xmin = 0, xmax = 15,
      ymin = 0, ymax = 8,
      xtick = {0, 5, 10, 15},
      ytick = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8},
    ]

      \addplot[black, no marks, domain=0.01:15, smooth]
      {f(x,23.3,42.2,3.15,1.86,3.38)};
      %\addplot[black, no marks, domain=0.01:15, smooth]{(1.86*3.38*(42.2 - 23.3))/(x*(1 + (x/3.15)^(-3.38))^(1.86)*(1 + (x/3.15)^(3.38)))};
      \addlegendentry{fitted function}

      \addplot[red, no marks, domain=0.01:15, smooth]
      {f(x,23.8,43.6,1.38,12,3.01)};
      %\addplot[red, no marks, domain=0.01:15, smooth]{(12*3.01*(43.6 - 23.8))/(x*(1 + (x/1.38)^(-3.01))^(12)*(1 + (x/1.38)^(3.01)))};
      \addlegendentry{fitted function2}


    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]