# difference between \prime and `'` in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I believed that `\prime` is the appropriate code to insert a prime in math mode and assumed that it would be equivalent to type `'`. I find that  `\prime` inserts an ugly, large prime, whereas the `'` produces something ok. Is there an explanation?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$a'_{i}$ dürfen zu $x'_{i}$ nur

$a\prime_{i}$ dürfen zu $x\prime_{i}$ nur

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `$a'_{i}$` is actually `$a^{\prime}_{i}$`

Comment: you should almost never use `\prime` just use `'`

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87134/35864

Comment: I've taken the liberty of inserting a larger screenshot of your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You wrote,

> I find that `\prime` inserts an ugly, large prime, whereas the `'` produces something ok. Is there an explanation?

To address this question in depth, it's useful to check how `'` (in math mode) is defined relative to `\prime`.  Here's an excerpt from the current version (`2020-02-02, patch level 5`) of the LaTeX2e "kernel" -- lines 5939 to 5954 from `latex.ltx`, to be exact -- that provides the code that defines `'` in LaTeX. (The Plain-TeX definition of `'` is similar.)

```
\def\active@math@prime{^\bgroup\prim@s}
{\catcode`\'=\active \global\let'\active@math@prime}
\def\prim@s{%
  \prime\futurelet\@let@token\pr@m@s}
\def\pr@m@s{%
  \ifx'\@let@token
    \expandafter\pr@@@s
  \else
    \ifx^\@let@token
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@t
    \else
      \egroup
    \fi
  \fi}
\def\pr@@@s#1{\prim@s}
\def\pr@@@t#1#2{#2\egroup}
```

I won't claim that this code is easy to grasp. Here's the gist of what's going on.

- The instruction

  ```
  \catcode`\'=\active
  ```

  makes the character `'` ("apostrophe" or "prime") active, in the TeX sense of the word, if the character is encountered in math mode.
- The character is let to `\active@math@prime`, which is defined as `^\bgroup\prim@s`. Note the initiation of an exponent term via `^`, followed by `\bgroup` -- as well as the absence, for now, of a corresponding `\egroup` directive.
- `\prim@s`, in turn, is defined as `\prime\futurelet\@let@token\pr@m@s`. Finally, we encounter `\prime` -- yay! The `\prime` directive -- recall that it is executed in superscript mode, so the resulting symbol is smaller than the text-style version of `\prime` -- is followed by

  ```
  \futurelet\@let@token\pr@m@s
  ```

  `\futurelet\@let@token` assigns the next token to `\@let@token`. So, what does `\pr@m@s` do?
- The code for `\pr@m@s` covers 10 lines of code; it is by far the most complicated of the macros in this bunch. It basically tells LaTeX to compare the look-ahead token (via a couple of `\ifx` statements) to a number of possible alternatives. In fact, the code considers three alternatives.

  - If the look-ahead token *is not equal* to either `'` or `^`, then `\egroup` is issued -- meaning that the exponent term group is closed and can be processed by LaTeX -- and we're done. Whew!
  - If the next character is equal to `^` (as in, say, `g'^2`), code needed to handle the exponent term, including an `\egroup` directive, is executed. (In case you're curious: `g'^2` evaluates to `g^{\prime2}`. If you'd rather have the square term placed a bit further up, you will need to write `{g'}^2`.)
  - Finally, if the next character *is equal* to `'`, then (after some more stirring of the pot...) another round of `\prime\futurelet\@let@token\pr@m@s` is executed, i.e., another `\prime` directive is executed followed by some more looking ahead.

Remembering that `\bgroup` and `\egroup` evaluate to `{` and `}`, respectively, we come to the following conclusion: the code assures that `u'v` gets interpreted as `u^{\prime}v`, `w''x` gets interpreted as `w^{\prime\prime}x`, `f'''` gets interpreted as `f^{\prime\prime\prime}`, etc. What's really important is to notice that `w''x` it NOT interpreted as `w^{\prime}^{\prime}x`, as that would trigger a dreaded "Double superscript" error.

In short, (a) typing `f\prime\prime` does not trigger an error message but is most definitely incorrect from a typographic perspective; (b) `f^{\prime\prime}` is both typographically and syntactically correct but also exceedingly tedious; (c) `f''` is both correct and easy. Can you guess which method is recommended? For what it's worth, my impression is that Donald Knuth intended users to input `f'` and `f''` all along.

Comment: One further consideration, regarding the size of the bare `\prime`.  Occasionally, not very often, a prime is used as a subscript.  By providing a "text-size" prime shape, it can be used very easily as either a superscript or subscript in the expected size.  And yes, I am sure that Knuth intended users to input `f'` and `f''` -- after all, he and his secretary were the first users, entering the text for *The Art of Computer Programming*, where it would both streamline entry and yield a nicely readable file.

Comment: In ConTeXt (and maybe in the LaTeX Unicode engines) the input `f'` actually becomes `′` with U+1D453 MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL F and U+2032 PRIME.

Comment: @HenriMenke - Thanks. To those of us :-) not as familiar with the difference between the "ordinary" math-italic lowercase letter "f" and U+1D453 MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL F, could you say a word (or maybe post a separate answer) on this subject? I'm sure quite a few people (me included!) would find this very interesting.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Many thanks for offering this historically very valuable first-hand reflection.

Comment: Now I (mostly) understand what is going on. I did not expect that much complication and the answer is overwhelming, but clear enough documented to be understandable! Again, thank you very much!