# How does cprotect work?

Tags: cprotect

We know that `cprotect` package can be used to include verbatim content in title/section: `\cprotect\section{\verb+123+}`.

- How does it work?
- If I want to do something similar that the package cannot do by itself, how can I?

Comment: (I can't find an existing question/answer, and I feel that having a summary of the documentation is beneficial for me before reading the source code documentation. The source code documentation is quite long and contains some uninteresting details such as how to parse verbatim balanced argument)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `cprotect` source code documentation ([on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/cprotect)) for details how it works.

In short:

To understand how `\cprotect` works, we first have to understand how `\protect` works.

Recall that [`\protect` ensures that the macro following it remains unexpanded, until
it's in a normal context](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/250119).

For `\verb` and similar, we need a stronger requirement, that is, the argument following it
must not be read (tokenized) until `\verb` is executed in a normal context.

So to do that, `\cprotect` essentially (*) transforms

```
\cprotect\section{\verb+abc+}
```

to

```
\section{\protect\input{a-1.cpt}}
```

after writing `\verb+abc+` to the file `a-1.cpt`.

This works, because `\protect` ensures that the file fed to `\input` is only tokenized in a normal context.

Of course, this (as well as `\protect`) relies on the content being eventually executed in a normal context.
If the argument is, for example, passed directly to `\detokenize` after only being expanded/never expanded at all,
it will not result in the final expected value. [Example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/548178/250119).

(*): actually the result is `\protect\input a-1.cpt\relax`.

Comment: There's also a little detail that it append `^^E^^L` at the end of the cpt file (just read the generated cpt file to see it.) to gobble the new line at the end of the file.

Comment: (similar to how if you write `\a \b` then the space between is gobbled by `\a`, because `a` is a letter.