# why i am getting this error while entering 6*6 matrix in beamer? "Missing { inserted. \end{frame}"

Tags: beamer, matrices

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{State-space Model of Proposed System}
    \vspace{-5cm} \tiny
        \begin{equation} \tiny
        A =  - B\left[{\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
    {{r_s}}&{\frac{{{\omega _e}}}{{{\omega _b}}}{X_{ss}}}&0&0&{\frac{{{\omega _e}}}{{{\omega _b}}}{X_M}}&0\\
    { - \frac{{{\omega _e}}}{{{\omega _b}}}{X_{ss}}}&{{r_s}}&0&{ - \frac{{{\omega _e}}}{{{\omega _b}}}{X_M}}&0&0\\
    0&0&{{r_s}}&0&0&0\\
    0&{\frac{{{\omega _e} - {\omega _r}}}{{{\omega _b}}}{X_M}}&0&{r_r^'}&{\frac{{{\omega _e} - {\omega _r}}}{{{\omega _b}}}X_{rr}^'}&0\\
    { - \frac{{{\omega _e} - {\omega _r}}}{{{\omega _b}}}{X_M}}&0&0&{ - \frac{{{\omega _e} - {\omega _r}}}{{{\omega _b}}}X_{rr}^'}&{r_r^'}&0\\
    0&0&0&0&0&{r_r^'}
    \end{array}} \right]
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are _a lot_ of useless curly braces in your code, so the error might come from that. Maybe you should try to rewrite the matrix with a more simple syntax. Also, instead of using ``\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} ... \end{array}} \right]`` you could use simply ``\begin{bmatrix} ... \end{bmatrix}``.

Comment: using bmatrix instead of array didn't solve my error.

Comment: No, I think what should solve your error is rather to rewrite the matrix with less unnecessary curly braces. For example, why writing ``\frac{{{\omega _e}}}{{{\omega _b}}}`` instead of ``\frac{\omega_e}{\omega_b}``? There are so much ``{`` and ``}``, it is certainly easy to make a typo and to have a ``{`` missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, that you would like to have slide like this:

[image]

In your MWE the following was done:

- removed error as is also suggested in @BambOo answer
- removed are all unnecessary curly braces
- used is the `nccmath` package (which load `amsmath` that can be used `\mfrac`, a medium sized fractions, and environment `\medmath`, which reduce size of equations
- instead of `array` with wrong numbered columns (20, but you use only 6!) is used `bmatrix`
- removed are all `\tiny` commands (one of them wrong placed)
- removed `\vspace{-5cm}` which ruin the look of the slide-

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{nccmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{graphicx} loaded by beamer

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{State-space Model of Proposed System}
    \begin{equation}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \medmath{
A =  - B \begin{bmatrix}
r_s & \mfrac{\omega_e}{\omega_b} X_{ss}
        & 0 & 0 & \mfrac{\omega_e}{\omega_b} X_M 
                    & 0     \\
-\mfrac{\omega_e}{\omega_b} X_{ss}
    & r_s
        & 0 & -\mfrac{\omega_e}{\omega_b} X_M
                & 0 & 0     \\
0   & 0 & r_s
            & 0 & 0 & 0     \\
0   & \mfrac{\omega_e - \omega_r}{\omega_b} X_M
        & 0 & r_r'
                & \mfrac{\omega_e - \omega_r}{\omega_b} X_{rr}'
                    & 0     \\
- \mfrac{\omega_e - \omega_r}{\omega _b} X_M
    & 0 & 0 & -\mfrac{\omega_e - \omega_r}{\omega _b} X_{rr}'
                    & r_r'  & 0 \\
0   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & r_r'
        \end{bmatrix}}
    \end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Equation can be written in normal size, if we introduce new variable `$\Delta\omega=\omega_e-\omega_r$`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{State-space Model of Proposed System}
    \begin{equation}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \medmath{
A =  - B \begin{bmatrix}
r_s & \mfrac{\omega_e}{\omega_b} X_{ss}
        & 0 & 0 & \mfrac{\omega_e}{\omega _b} X_M 
                    & 0     \\
-\mfrac{\omega_e}{\omega_b} X_{ss}
    & r_s
        & 0 & -\mfrac{\omega_e}{\omega_b} X_M
                & 0 & 0     \\
0   & 0 & r_s
            & 0 & 0 & 0     \\
0   & \mfrac{\omega_e - \omega_r}{\omega_b} X_M
        & 0 & r_r'
                & \mfrac{\omega_e - \omega_r}{\omega_b} X_{rr}'
                    & 0     \\
- \mfrac{\omega_e - \omega_r}{\omega _b} X_M
    & 0 & 0 & -\mfrac{\omega_e - \omega_r}{\omega _b} X_{rr}'
                    & r_r'  & 0 \\
0   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & r_r'
        \end{bmatrix}}
    \end{equation}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{State-space Model of Proposed System (normal size)}
    \begin{equation}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
A =  - B \begin{bmatrix}
r_s & \mfrac{\omega_e}{\omega_b} X_{ss}
        & 0 & 0 & \mfrac{\omega_e}{\omega _b} X_M
                    & 0     \\
-\mfrac{\omega_e}{\omega_b} X_{ss}
    & r_s
        & 0 & -\mfrac{\omega_e}{\omega_b} X_M
                & 0 & 0     \\
0   & 0 & r_s
            & 0 & 0 & 0     \\
0   & \mfrac{\Delta\omega}{\omega_b} X_M
        & 0 & r_r'
                & \mfrac{\Delta\omega}{\omega_b} X_{rr}'
                    & 0     \\
- \mfrac{\Delta\omega}{\omega _b} X_M
    & 0 & 0 & -\mfrac{\Delta\omega}{\omega _b} X_{rr}'
                    & r_r'  & 0 \\
0   & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & r_r'
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
where $\Delta\omega=\omega_e-\omega_r$.
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes sir.. i need frame like this only.. i got your point.. it helped me solved my error...

Answer (score 0):

While you code is pretty ugly due to the braces everywhere, the error comes from the fact that you type `^'`. However `'` is actually defined as `^{\prime}` as stated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87140/141947). Just replace `^'` with `'` and it compiles fine.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{State-space Model of Proposed System}
    \vspace{-5cm} \tiny
        \begin{equation} \tiny
        A =  - B\left[{\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
    {{r_s}}&{\frac{{{\omega _e}}}{{{\omega _b}}}{X_{ss}}}&0&0&{\frac{{{\omega _e}}}{{{\omega _b}}}{X_M}}&0\\
    { - \frac{{{\omega _e}}}{{{\omega _b}}}{X_{ss}}}&{{r_s}}&0&{ - \frac{{{\omega _e}}}{{{\omega _b}}}{X_M}}&0&0\\
    0&0&{{r_s}}&0&0&0\\
    0&{\frac{{{\omega _e} - {\omega _r}}}{{{\omega _b}}}{X_M}}&0&{r_r'}&{\frac{{{\omega _e} - {\omega _r}}}{{{\omega _b}}}X_{rr}'}&0\\
    { - \frac{{{\omega _e} - {\omega _r}}}{{{\omega _b}}}{X_M}}&0&0&{ - \frac{{{\omega _e} - {\omega _r}}}{{{\omega _b}}}X_{rr}'}&{r_r'}&0\\
    0&0&0&0&0&{r_r'}
    \end{array}} \right]
\end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir..This solved my error... thanks again for well explaination....i got it..